# Does Dorsal Raphe Nuclei firing pattern change in response to voluntary breathing?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, sleep

I'm reading this paper, which discusses how Serotonin may be involved in motor functions of mammals: [5-HT and motor control: a hypothesis](http://www.princeton.edu/~sswang/awake_cerebellar_ms_refs/jacobs_fornal93_TINS.pdf) .

The paper includes the following diagram of the Dorsal Raphe Nuclei (DRN) firing pattern in a walking cat, and cat on a tredmill. Each step is associated with a distinct firing pattern. **I'm wandering if the DRN firing pattern, in humans, changes in a similar way in response to voluntary breathing?**

[image: Dorsal Raphe Nuclei Firing pattern]

After searching wikipedia, I found a line that says:

> REM sleep is turned on by acetylcholine secretion and is inhibited by
>   neurons that secrete serotonin. ([Psysiology of sleep stages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_stages#Physiology))

I'm interested in dreaming, and at times have practiced entering dreams consciously, from the waking state after laying in bed for a long time. One of the obstacles to entring a dream was seizing control of breathing and starting to breathe voluntarily. This prevented me from entering dreams on a number of occasions, and appears to support the idea that voluntary breathing would affect the DRN. But I'm looking for a more scientifically-validated answer.

Thank you for your input!